# Limit the input length of a DevExpress TextEdit and MemoEdit controls

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a project with some 3rd-party controls in it. I have a TextEdit and a MemoEdit in my form and I want to limit the number of characters that the user can enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the newest version but there are a few workarounds such as masking, helper properties and/or character counting on the text changed event. Here are some links to the workarounds:

Mask workaround: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q250641.aspx

Helper property workaround: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S131769.aspx

Text change/char count: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/6776-Text-edit-and-maxLength

Comment: I think that is for a WPF form

Comment: See this note from one of the posts: `Even though it is devoted to WPF editors, this functionality will also be included in AgEditors, because they share the same sources.` Masking has been supported in WinForms controls too.

Comment: Okey, thanks ... In the newest version of Devexpress there is a feature that allows to limit the maxLenght (textEdit.properties.MaxLenght), i just need to upgarde my version ;)