# Limit Length (Character input) in MemoEdit (DevExpress)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I'm using the following code (based on `devexpress` help fora) to prevent the user to give in more then `48 characters` a line in a `MemoEdit`

```
Private Sub txtAuthors_EditValueChanging(sender As System.Object, e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs) Handles txtAuthors.EditValueChanging
    If e.NewValue Is Nothing Then
        'No Value found in memoEditor
        Return
    End If
    'Max lenght of textbox
    Dim maxLength As Integer = 48
    Dim edit As DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit = TryCast(sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit)
    For Each str As String In edit.Lines
        If str.Length > maxLength Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Return
        End If
    Next str
End Sub
```

This function prevents the insertion of String with more then 48 characters. But what I actually wish to achieve is the following:

**My Goal:**
If the user enters a new string (using `Ctrl + V/Paste`) with `more than 48 chars`. it should not prevent all the data from being entered. The control should except `the first 48 chars` en ditch the rest.
How to achieve this behavior. I've tried to manipulate `e.NewValue` but to no avail...

**Remark about the `Lines`-property:**

```
You are not able to use the Lines property to change a particular array's element
directly. Instead, you should read the Lines property to get the array, change 
the required array's element and then assign the array back to Lines.
```

**Note**: Ive read this ([Limit the input length of a DevExpress TextEdit and MemoEdit controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12467674/3099117)) but it didn't help

**Note 2:** The input being given inside the MemoEdit may vary from ordinary user-input (pressing any key or `Ctrl + V`) to computerbased-input coming from a WCF-Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial & errors (with some infinite loops added to the mix), I've managed to find a good (not perfect) solution. I Hope the following code might be of some use to anyone.

```
 Public Sub EditValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txt.EditValueChanged

    Dim edit As DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit = TryCast(sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit)
    'Take copy of the array
    Dim myStringArrayCopy As String() = control.Lines
    Dim hasEdits As Boolean = False

    For Each str As String In myStringArrayCopy
        If str.Length > maxCharCount Then
            Dim indexString As Integer = Array.IndexOf(myStringArrayCopy, str)
            myStringArrayCopy(indexString) = str.Substring(0, 47)
            hasEdits = True
        End If
    Next str

    If (hasEdits) Then
        control.Lines = myStringArrayCopy
        control.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have a couple of remarks to this code.

**Remark 1:** Use EditValueChanged instead of EditValueChanging. It makes more sense to modify the textbox after the edit has been made instead of in the middle.

**Remark 2:** If an edit has been made with more then 48 chars. Then the string will be shortened but the cursor will be placed on the firstline (this is a multiline txt)

**Remark 3:** Don't forget the refresh(). Otherwise the changes being made won't be visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Using a standard winform textbox this can be achieved by handling the `KeyDown` event, look for `Ctrl + V` keys and check the `Cliboard` text.

```
Private Sub txtAuthors_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtAuthors.KeyDown
    If ((e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.V)) Then
        Dim text As String = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
        If (text.Length > 48) Then
            My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(text.Substring(0, 48))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: I do not have devexpress installed, so I cannot guarantee this will work for the `MemoEdit` control.

Comment: The problem is that the input can vary from userinput (using Ctrl + V) to computerinput. Therefor is the EditValuechanged (similar to textchanged of textbox) more suitable. I've modified my question to include this.